# function from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: geometry

Suppose $\phi:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}^{3}$ by $\phi(x_1,x_2)= (u(x_1,x_2),v(x_1,x_2),w(x_1,x_2))$ is a smooth function. Furthermore, suppose that $\alpha:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is a smooth curve given by $\alpha(t) = (f(t),g(t))$. Using the chain rule, find an expression for $\frac{d}{dt}(\phi(\alpha(t))$, in terms of $u,v,w,f$ and $g$ (and/or their derivatives).

Comment: And what aspect of this problem are you having trouble with?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain properly, I'm confused about nearly every aspect. I know what the chain rule is but I don't know how to find the given expression. And I'm not sure what the relationship between a smooth function and a smooth curve is and why its relevant.

Comment: A smooth function, curve, or whatever is one that has continuous derivatives of all orders at all of its points. Note that this condition does not imply the function can be expanded as a power series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immediately from the question:

$\frac{d}{dt}(\phi(\alpha(t))) = \frac{d}{dt}\big( u(f(t),g(t)),v(f(t),g(t)),w(f(t),g(t))\big)$

Now you can use the chain rule on each component yourself.

$ = \big( \frac{d}{dt}u(f(t),g(t)),\frac{d}{dt}v(f(t),g(t)),\frac{d}{dt}w(f(t),g(t))\big)$

The functions are only said to be smooth to justify differentiation.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So does that mean that for example taking $\frac{d}{dt} u(f(t),g(t)) = \frac{\partial{\alpha}}{\partial{u}} = \frac{\partial{\alpha}}{\partial{f(t)}}\frac{\partial{f(t)}}{\partial{u}}+\frac{\partial{\alpha}}{\partial{g(t)}}\frac{\partial{g(t)}}{\partial{u}}$

Comment: And once i have that for $\frac{d}{dt} u(f(t),g(t))$ then what do I do? Do I do the same thing for the other components and once i get the different expressions, how do I present my answer?